# How Does FirstOrDefault Test for Equality?

Tags: c#, linq, equality

I have a reference type that implements the IEquatable Interface. I have a Hashset that contains a single object. I then create an object that, by IEquatable's standards are example the same. But, when I run

```
var equivalentEntry = _riskControlATMEntries[grouping.Key].FirstOrDefault(e => e == atmEntry);
```

on the object I get null.

On the otherhand when I do

```
var equivalentEntry = _riskControlATMEntries[grouping.Key].FirstOrDefault(e => e.Equals(atmEntry));
```

I get the object that is considered equal based on the IEquatable interface's implementation.

So why does a HashSet rely on `public bool Equals(ReferenceType other)` but `FirstOrDefault` does not? What equality is the `==` operator in `FirstOrDefault(e => e == other)` looking for?

Comment: A `HashSet` only checks equality for items with the same hashcode. You need to overrride the `GetHashCode` method and implement it in a way that equal objects will return the same hashcode.

Comment: @Knoop Ahhh Got it. I thought it uses the Equals method. I have both Equals and GetHashCode overriden. What about my question on FirstOrDefault's equality comparison?

Comment: You can also directly overload the operators your're interested in. `public static bool operator ==(MyClass first, MyClass second)`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` doesn't compare items for equality at all.  You provided a filtering delegate that uses the `==` operator to compare the two objects in one case and used the `Equals` method in the other.

The `==` operator does whatever the class defines it to do by that type, or if not defined, by the closest base type that does (with `object` being the base type that is always there, and will always have a definition if nothing better was defined; it will compare objects based on their reference).  Good design says that you should make sure the `==` operator for a class is defined to behave exactly the same as the `Equals` method, but nothing in the language forces you to do this, and apparently this class doesn't ensure they're the same, and it's unsurprisingly causing you problems.